# Unable to add the logo in Customize Branding Section in Windows Azure Active Directory

Tags: windows-store-apps, azure-active-directory

I have been trying to add a logo for a windows azure active directory account.

I have added a banner logo, square logo and sign in text, when I tried to save the logo it returning an error like below.

I have followed the logo guidelines and still facing this issue. Is the issue from Microsoft or any other issue?

[image]

Few days ago I uploaded the logo I faced the same issue and now I tried to add the logo still im facing the same issue.

Anybody can please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Azure AD portal is notorious for generic error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate the error - if you add a banner logo, a square logo, a Sign-In Page Text Heading and then on the next page a Sign-In Page Illustration it will throw out that error.

If you either remove the Sign-In Page Text Heading, or add Sign-In Page Text it will apply the settings happily.

Hope that helps!